C# code runs fine as a console app but fails as a Word Add-In
I am a bit of a hack when it comes to C#.  I am trying to write an Office Add-in that allows the user to select some text in a word document an then call an Azure language service API.  The call works fine when I created a standalone windows console app:
 Debug.WriteLine("beginning of the try");
 string azureEndpoint = "https://redacted.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"; // Replace with your actual endpoint URL
 string subscriptionKey = "redacted"; // Replace with your actual subscription key

 Uri endpoint = new Uri(azureEndpoint);
 AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(subscriptionKey);

 QuestionAnsweringClient client = new QuestionAnsweringClient(endpoint, credential);

 string projectName = "redacted";
 string deploymentName = "production";
 QuestionAnsweringProject project = new QuestionAnsweringProject(projectName, deploymentName);
 Response<AnswersResult> response = client.GetAnswers("Where is your headquarters?", project);

 foreach (KnowledgeBaseAnswer answer in response.Value.Answers)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine($"({answer.Confidence:P2}) {answer.Answer}");
     Debug.WriteLine($"Source: {answer.Source}");
     Debug.WriteLine($"Confidence:  {answer.Confidence}");
 }

However, when I try to tie the same code to a button in an office add-in, I get errors (10054, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host).  Note that I have tried to use async - it didn't seem to make a difference.
private void button7_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
    rng.Select();
    var selectedText = rng.Text;

    try
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("beginning of the try");
         string azureEndpoint = "https://redacted.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"; // Replace with your actual endpoint URL
        string subscriptionKey = "redacted"; // Replace with your actual subscription key

        Uri endpoint = new Uri(azureEndpoint);
        AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(subscriptionKey);

        QuestionAnsweringClient client = new QuestionAnsweringClient(endpoint, credential);

        string projectName = "redacted";
        string deploymentName = "production";
        QuestionAnsweringProject project = new QuestionAnsweringProject(projectName, deploymentName);
        Response<AnswersResult> response = client.GetAnswers("Where is your headquarters?", project);

        foreach (KnowledgeBaseAnswer answer in response.Value.Answers)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"({answer.Confidence:P2}) {answer.Answer}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Source: {answer.Source}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Confidence:  {answer.Confidence}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions (e.g., network errors, invalid response)
        MessageBox.Show("Error calling Azure Language Service API: " + ex.Message );
    }
}

The error is this:  retry failed after 4 tries

"I get errors" - what errors?

It is at the bottom of the post.  An exception is caught with the error "retry failed after 4 tries"

"Retry failed after 4 tries" is not the actual error - it means that something else failed first which led to the retry; you need to tell us what that initial failure/error is.

From the console:
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in Azure.AI.Language.QuestionAnswering.dll
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (34896) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
If I print out the full exception, nothing really jumps out at me.  It says that the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Check your Azure services’ network security settings -or things like Private Endpoints - or even if your ISP is blocking anything.

Thank you, I appreciate the responses.  As I noted in my post, the other block of code is working on the same computer in a different project (windows console app) using the exact same settings.  The app that isn't working is an add-in that is tied to a button.  This makes me think that there is something about the environments that I do not fully understand.

As noted earlier, I did try to use async.  Am I doing it right?
Would the async be tied to the button?  private async void button7_Click......

I updated the post to include a new discovery - I am getting a '10054' error in my debugger.

I never did figure this out, so I abandoned it in favor of using office.js.   I had no such problems there.

I abandoned using .net in favor of office.js.  I had no problems using the same endpoints there.
